# Dynamic row comparison in one table - DAX / M language / Power BI

Tags: compare, powerbi, rows, dax, m

Is this possible?

I've got a table, with a column containing the **version** of product (for example: *fast car*).
Every version has a list of **parts** (for example: *color*).
Every part has a number of **values** (for example: *red*).

`VERSION     PART    PART_VALUE
VERSION1    PART1   PART_VALUE1
VERSION1    PART2   PART_VALUE2
VERSION1    PART3   PART_VALUE3
VERSION2    PART2   PART_VALUE2
VERSION2    PART3   PART_VALUE3
VERSION2    PART4   PART_VALUE4
VERSION3    PART1   PART_VALUE1
VERSION3    PART2   PART_VALUE2
VERSION3    PART3   PART_VALUE4`

Now I want to select - in Fragmentator or in some other checkbox -
**Version1** and **Version2** and the results should be:

`"ONLY DIFFENCES BETWEEN VERSION1 AND VERSION2"

VERSION1    PART1   PART_VALUE1
VERSION2    PART4   PART_VALUE4`

or after selecting **Version1** and **Version3** the results should be:

`"ONLY DIFFENCES BETWEEN VERSION1 AND VERSION3"

VERSION1    PART3   PART_VALUE3
VERSION3    PART3   PART_VALUE4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an M query which should do what you want:

```
(V1, V2) =>
let
    Source = MyTable,
    First = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([VERSION] = V1)),
    Second = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([VERSION] = V2)),
    #"First Unique" = Table.NestedJoin(First,{"PART", "PART_VALUE"},Second,{"PART", "PART_VALUE"},"Second",JoinKind.LeftAnti),
    #"Second Unique" = Table.NestedJoin(Second,{"PART", "PART_VALUE"},First,{"PART", "PART_VALUE"},"First",JoinKind.LeftAnti),
    Combine = Table.Combine({#"First Unique", #"Second Unique"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Combine,{"Second", "First"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: can You help one more time? if I want to add another column called ***Indeks*** and before ***Joins*** do something like filter on this table

Comment: Just insert your `Add Column` step before the `First` and `Second` filter steps, and amend those filters to suit your requirement.

Comment: I've got this parametrs : ***V1*** and ***V2***, and I type their values into input by keyboard. My question is, can this value by defined by *dictionary*  or *dynamic dropdown list*?

Comment: Yes. Use a list query as a parameter source.

Comment: can you give some link to example of use parametr for my ***V1*** and ***V1***?